# Why does my file show up blank in python?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to get my python file to save numbers into a text file, but it always goes blank when I try it. I've done this many times before but it refuses to work this time.

```
openfile = 'example'
total = 0.5 #another example
totalstr = str(total)
file = open("%s.txt" % (openfile), "w")
file.write(totalstr)
file.close
```

Comment: Why are the file lines indented?

Comment: it's `.close()`, you missed the `()` ;)

Comment: In `openfile = file` make the file as a string `file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"file" is a standard Python type. You want to rename things a bit. I'm also assuming "openfile" should be the string filename you want to use. Both answers so far are correct but putting them together gives:

```
my_file_name = "myfile"
total = 0.5
my_file_handle = open("%s.txt" %(my_file_name), "w")
my_file_handle.write(str(total))
my_file_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a keyword in python. So,

```
print '%s' %(file)
```

prints

```
<type 'file'>
```

You should use:

```
openfile = 'file'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
openfile = "file"
total = 0.5
totalstr = str(total)
file = open("%s.txt" % (openfile), "w")
file.write(totalstr)
file.close()
```

See if you can spot the changes.